# sql query for the below pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table : Name

When I do a : **SELECT * FROM Name**, it give the results as :

```
Name
======
aaa
bbb
ccc
sss
```

I want the result to be like in one row only :

```
Name
====
aaa bbb ccc sss
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Is this results you want from the query, or the final data you want to work with.  I am not sure you can just append every name into one field, and i doubt it will  return one row with multiples of the same field (i.e. name, name, name) ... what is your purpose for this data.

Comment: The requirement is to support some old pattern..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      col NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (col)
VALUES 
    ('aaa'),
    ('bbb'),
    ('ccc'),
    ('sss')

SELECT str_string = (
    SELECT col + ' '
    FROM @temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```

Or try this -

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @string = @string + col + ' '
FROM @temp

SELECT @string
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT ColumnName + ' '
    FROM YourTable
    FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')  AS [Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

May be over-egging the pudding for your requirement but a CLR aggregate function for concatenating rows into single values is a very handy thing to have in your toolbox. Something like below. Runs much faster than xml in my experience, and supports GROUP BY etc so is quite powerful. Only works in SQL2k8 or above and will blow up if it concats a string to over 2GB.

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined, MaxByteSize = -1)]
public struct Concatenate : IBinarySerialize
{
public string concat;
public string delimiter;

public void Init()
{
    this.concat = "";
}

public void Accumulate(SqlString text, SqlString delim)
{
    if (!text.IsNull)
    {
        concat += (string)text + (string)delim;
    }
    delimiter = (string)delim;
}

public void Merge(Concatenate Group)
{
    concat += (string)Group.concat + (string)Group.delimiter;
    delimiter = (string)Group.delimiter;
}

public SqlString Terminate()
{
    return concat.Substring(0, concat.Length - delimiter.Length);
}

public void Read(BinaryReader r)
{
    delimiter = r.ReadString();
    concat = r.ReadString();
}

public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
{
    w.Write(delimiter);
    w.Write(concat);
}
```

}